# How to upgrade jre selectively on linux mint

Tags: linux, ubuntu, package-management

I have newly started using linux mint (linux at all).

I have installed two jre versions on it. One openjdk and another oracle jdk. Here is how my update-alternatives --config java output says -

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status

------------------------------------------------------------
0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      auto mode
1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0_13/bin/java                2         manual mode
```

I want to upgrade oracle jre listed at #2 above. Is there a way to selectively upgrade that?

Here is what I tried:
1. I tried finding this jre in package manager but I couldn't find it, may be because I manually installed it.
2. Did 'apt-get update' and tried to find oracle java in 'apt-cache search' so that I can upgrade from there, but again couldn't find oracle java in search.

The final approach that I am thinking of trying is to download latest version and install it along with 1.7.0_13 and making that choice. However, I want a way to upgrade existing.

Any inputs?

Comment: I see the question was closed, for my understanding, since this was my first question on stackoverflow, can somebody tell me why was it closed as off topic? I have been reading 'what not to ask' FAQ, but am not able to understand how my question could be off topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu and other Linux distributions usually provide a custom linux version (such as openJDK). To install the official versions, I recommend you to use this site: http://www.devsniper.com/ubuntu-12-04-install-sun-jdk-6-7/, from where I took the steps to install it in my machine.

There is also this option, that talks specifically about Linux Mint and is simmilar : http://www.vivaolinux.com.br/dica/Instalando-Java-no-Linux-Mint-Ubuntu-e-derivados

Comment: I actually already have the version of java I want, installed along with open JDK. I just want to upgrade that, selectively. And I am trying to find how to do that

Comment: Upgrade selectively ??? I believe every time a new version is released you need to repeat the whole process. As far as I know, there is no way to simply upgrade one of the versions, you need to re-install the new version you downloaded from the oracle website.

Comment: Yes, looks like the only way to do it. Thanks

Comment: Yes, i think so. Are u new on stackoverflow? Rating positively people who help you solve your problems is good for many reasons: it improves you rating, it improves my rating and it helps people with the same problem to find your question through standard search. Cheers

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation yet to do so